# Traveling Salesman Problem: Big O Complexity of Algorithm

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

I'm trying to figure out how to do this problem in my intro algorithm class, but I'm a little confused.

> The Traveling Salesman problem (TSP) is famous.  Given a list of
>   cities and the distances in between them, the task is to find the
>   shortest possible ​tour​ that starts at a city, visits each city
>   exactly once and returns to a starting city. A particular tour can be
>   described as list of all cities [c1,c2, c3, ... ,cn] ordered by the
>   position in which they are visited with the assumption that you return
>   from the last city to the start.This is a hard problem, that is, there
>   is no known efficient solution for this problem and we are not
>   expecting one any time soon. Your task is to analyze the following
>   brute force approach to solving the problem:
>
> Consider the following algorithm for solving the TSP:
>
> ```
> n = number of cities
> m = n x n matrix of distances between cities
> min = (infinity)
> for all possible tours do:
>     find the length of the tour
>     if length < min:
>          min = length
>          store tour
> ```
>
> State the worst-case (big-O) complexity of this algorithm in terms of
>   ​​(number of cities)?You may assume that matrix lookup is one step
>   O(1). For deriving big-O here, you need not count the if-statement or
>   the for-loop conditional (i.e., testing to see when the for-loop is
>   done), or any of the initializations at the start of the algorithm.

So far I know that there are 2 statements that will be executed after the if statement and I think there n! permutations of tours. Am I correct so far. How would I figure out the amounts of steps for "find the length of tour"?

Answer (score 2):

You've almost got it! Remember, you're going to visit each city exactly once in a tour. Which means you have to look up $n-1$ distances for each one. This is $O(n)$, since the problem specifies that matrix lookup is assumed to be $O(1)$.

Comment: So would the big O notation be O((n-1)!)? Or would it be O((n-1!) + O(1)?

Comment: @John You can ignore lower-order terms, but you can't ignore lower-order *factors*. So it's $O(n!n)$: $O(n!)$ different paths to look at, $O(n)$ work for each path.

Answer (score 0):

The tour is exactly $n$ elements list, where $n$ is number of cities. So it takes n - 1 additions and one check if it is smaller than already seen.

You are right that there are $n!$ permutations, but last city is fixed, so $(n-1)!$ tours. If problem is symmetric you can divide number of permutations by 2. It changes nothing in big-O notation.

You have to get these permutations, but it is also negligible. This yields $\mathcal O(n! * n)$ worst case runtime. In fact, $\mathcal O(\frac{(n-1)!}{2} * (n - 1))$ is of exactly same order as previous one.

If you add 'if' statements, you will get something like 3(n-1) which is still simply $\mathcal O(n)$.

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused. The total number of permutations is (n-1)! so would the big O notation be O((n-1)!) because we can ignore the lower order terms?

Comment: No, we can ignore constant factors (like 3, -1), but you $n!$ times run something linear (3n or so), so you cannot ignore this factor. $\mathcal O(n! * n)$ is not the same as $\mathcal O(n!)$. $n$ here is variable, not constant, In soft big-O ( Õ ) you can ignore logarithmic factors, but still not linear or bigger. You can check whether $n*n! \in \mathcal O(n!)$ to be sure.

Comment: Okay. If there are (n-1)! total tours because the last city is fixed, then how did you get O(n!*n) and not O((n-1)!)?

Comment: Because it does not matter whether it is n! or (n-1)! in asymptotic case. n! times you check the length n, this minimal tour distance is accounted for. (n-1)! * n, where (n-1)! is number of possible tours and n is number of cities to add distances. O(1) in your excersise means that looking up value is constant time, so we count it as 1. I honestly think, that you should convince yourself that c*n = $\mathcal O(n)$ and then look at current problem once again.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Last question, why did you multiply (n-1)! by n and not add (n-1)! and n?

Comment: If you 3 times walk 5km, is it 8km or 15km? Here it is the same case: foreach(tour) {add n - 1 distances and check it with current min}. You add about n elements in tour number 1, 2, 3, ..., n!